# No overload for 'GameCanvas_Loaded' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler' and `PlayAgain_Click`

Tags: c#, overloading

im doing a tetris game with a tutorial it works for him but not to for me idk what to do it does not work for me

```
<Window x:Class="tetris.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tetris"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Tetris" Height="600" Width="800"
        MinWidth = "600" MinHeight = "600"
        Foreground = "White"
        FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="28"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Background.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Viewbox   Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas"
                Background="#101010"
                Width="250"
                Height="500"
                ClipToBounds="True"
                    Loaded="GameCanvas_Loaded"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SourceText"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="Score: "
                   Margin="0,10"
                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock Text="Hold"
                       TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image x:Name="HoldImage"
                   Margin="20"
                   Width="125"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Next"
                       TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image x:Name="NextImage"
                   Margin="20"
                   Width="125"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="GameOverMenu"
              Background="#cc000000"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Visibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Game Over"
                           FontSize="48"
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="FinalScoreText"
                           Text="Score"
                           FontSize="36"
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="PlayAgain"
                        Background="LightGreen"
                       Margin="0,20,0,0"
                        Padding="5"
                        Click="PlayAgain_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

but they were not in the .cs file like =  private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)                   i only have this one / but the guy in the tutorial had these two too=

```
private void GameCanvas_Loaded(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
           
}
private void PlayAgain_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}  i added these two by my self but it did not work .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To subscribe an event (e.g., `Loaded` or `Click`), you handler (e.g., `GameCanvas_Loaded`) must match with the event's type. Both these events require the second parameter to be `RoutedEventArgs`. Check [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). You usually don't need to write the handlers manually, if you write `Load="` in your IDE, it will suggest creating a handler for you.

```cs
private void GameCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
           
}
private void PlayAgain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```